# Jquery to decrease size after 100% to 33.3%

Tags: jquery

I got a small issue here.
Iv'e tried this in two ways so far including adding and remove a class but with my current try im doing it via div size.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {

     $(".backlarger").click(function(){

            if ($(this).width() < 1000) {
                $(this).animate({ height: "900px" });
                $(this).animate({ width: "100%" }); 
              return false;
         } else if ($(this).width() > 800) {
                $(this).animate({ width: "33.3% !important" });
                $(this).animate({ height: "260px !important" });
                return false;
         } 
        }); 
     });
```

The above doesn't seem to close the div. 
As well I will have a few of these divs; would would be the best way to have one open at a time?

JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jzn7nub2/

Comment: Please provide `jsfiddle`,

Comment: Your question is not clear :(. can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my try our code on the first click increases width to 937px. 
Then on second click it still goes into the `if` branch and **`else if` will never get called.** 
Add `console.log($(this).width());` right before `if-else if` to see those numbers. 
To fix this, either check the height that will be exact number or just use `if-else` 
Try this

```
$(".backlarger").click(function(){
    if ($(this).height() < 300) {
      $(this).animate({ height: "900px" });
      $(this).animate({ width: "100%" }); 
       return false;
 } else if ($(this).height() >= 300) {
      $(this).animate({ width: "33.3%" });
        $(this).animate({ height: "260px" });
   } 
});
```

Or in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzn7nub2/1/)**

Comment: Hi, Sorry I should of noted I changed the numbers cause first they were below 300px and above 301px matching them; I even tried it without % and made them in the correct pixels but it appears that if it's larger than 33.3% it just doesn't go back.